# Multiple Docker containers to simulate multiple servers

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Does multiple Docker containers act as if they where separate servers?

Rephrased, my question is; Can I use multiple Docker containers on a single CI server to realistically test a PHP/MySQL/Nginx setup, where the MySQL is a separate server in the production setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure why not? I use a mysql container locally with a php/nginx app container connecting to it, but when deploy to a production environment (Amazon ECS + RDS) I set an environment flag to have the php app point to RDS.

What isn't clear in your question is how the CI server works, and what tests need to be done. But in the end to answer your question yes each docker container can be treated as a separate server.

Comment: Even though the containers run on the hardware in tests but not in production? The tests are for the pho code and are don through PHPUnit.

Comment: The code in your docker containers that is getting unit tested via PHPUnit should be the same code that is running in the container on any environment, hence the beauty of Docker. But how that code performs on different hardware might make a difference in production vs test if your resources aren't the same or similar. Here is a good article about resource management according to Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints

Comment: Thanks Chris - that answers my question :)